# Stop one code in a for-loop in unityscript

Tags: for-loop, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've got a for-loop which you can see at the bottom of this question, inside this for-loop are multiple if-statements, I want it that if one of those if-statement is called, that if-statement gets disabled for the rest of that for-loop. Is there anyway of doing that?

```
for (var i = 0; i < chunksInScene.length ; i++) {
    if(chunksInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "Chunk" || chunksInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "_TERR" || chunksInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5) == "ACTIV") {
        if(chunksInScene[i].tag != "Player") {
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk1)){load1 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk2)){load2 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk3)){load3 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk4)){load4 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk5)){load5 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk6)){load6 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk7)){load7 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk8)){load8 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk9)){load9 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk10)){load10 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk11)){load11 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk12)){load12 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk13)){load13 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk14)){load14 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk15)){load15 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk16)){load16 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk17)){load17 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk18)){load18 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk19)){load19 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk20)){load20 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk21)){load21 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk22)){load22 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk23)){load23 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk24)){load24 = false;continue;}
                if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk25)){load25 = false;continue;}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't want to stop the loop, but for the reminder of the loop ignore the `if` statement that executed. Then you need to create a condition for every if statement.

You can create an array of type `boolean` and set it to false once inside one of those `ifs`. Like this:

```
var myArray : boolean[] = new boolean[NUMBER_OF_IFs];

if(myArray[0] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk1)
{
   load1 = false;
   myArray[0] = false;
   continue;
}
```

You need to make sure that for each element of the array there is an element that represents an if statement.

---

This is how it would look like in your code:

```
var myArray : boolean[] = new boolean[25];

for (var i = 0; i < chunksInScene.length ; i++) 
{
   // I changed this part, the long if statement was driving me crazy.
   var temp = chuckInScene[i].name.Substring(0,5);

   if((temp == "Chunk" || temp == "_TERR" || temp == "ACTIV") && chunksInScene[i].tag != "Player")
   {
       if(myArray[0] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk1))
         {load1 = false; myArray[0] = false;continue;}

       if(myArray[1] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk2))
         {load2 = false; myArray[1] = false; continue;}

       if(myArray[2] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk3))
         {load3 = false; myArray[2] = false; continue;}

       .
       .
       .
       // You write the rest.
       if(myArray[25] && chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk25))
         {load25 = false; myArray[25]; continue;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand it good, I just started programming sorry, can you write the for loop for me please, so I can see better how it needs to be. Thank you.

Comment: @Jordi Answer this first, it matters. Do you want to stop the loop once one of those if statements executes? Or do you want the loop to continue running?

Comment: I want it that when for example the first if statement get called, it never gets called again, until the for loop is completely done.

Comment: @Jordi Then use my method. If you want to stop the loop use nicael's version. Also I hope you understand what an array is.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I understand now, but do I need to declare that array before the for-loop? I think I need to do so, but I'm not sure. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Jordi Yes declare it like it looks like in my post. Make sure you count how many `ifs` you have, so that number goes in the declaration of the array. I counted 25.

Comment: Okay, so I need to declare it before my first if-loop? Sorry for all those (probably stupid) question. As soon as this problem is solved, I'l accept your answer :)

Comment: Yep declare it outside the `for` loop and outside any `if`. I just added it above so you can see better. Good luck.

Comment: Okay thank you very very very much, I'm going to try it now :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `else` and whitespace after the each `if` statement. (exept of the last `if`)

```
if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk1){load1 = false;continue;}else
if(chunksInScene[i].Equals(chunk2){load2 = false;continue;}else
...
```

Comment: It gives me an error, I need to add a curly brace behind the last `else`

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, you could use delegates. Make each if statement a delegate, put them all in a Set, then just have the main loop going over the entire set. Once an if is triggered, remove it from the set and continue.